# React.js API for search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm very new to JavaScript and the world of React. I've learning hooks, and tried to fetch some API for searchbar and it doesn't work.

I'm trying to grab the data from the url (its array) and search bar to filter items by its title.

```
function Search() {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState([]);
    const [text,setText] = useState([]);
    
    const getAPI = async() => {
        const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
        const data = await response.json()
        setText(data.Search)
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        getAPI()
    }, [])

    return <div>
            <input 
                placeholder="searching"
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
};
```

Comment: you have to mention what you want to achieve and issues you are facing

Answer (score 0):

there is not any key with `Search` name inside response data you should setState all your data and then filter with input text value.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) documentation.

```
    useEffect( () => {
        getAPI()
    }, [])
```

The above code only runs when the component is mounted. When the user changes the value of `input`, `Search` component rerenders, because its state changes. But `useEffect` will not be executed because you have provided an empty array of dependencies.

1. You have declared `getAPI` inside your component. So you should probably add it to the array of dependencies of `useEffect`.
2. You should call `getAPI` in `onChange` of the input. So it fetches the data from server based on the query parameters.
3. You have not used `searchTerm` inside `getAPI` function.
4. Be aware of infinite loop caused by `useEffect`.